# Setting scrollbar starting position at certain height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know if it is possible in js/ jquery/ css/ html to set a start position on a scrollbar.

[image]

In the screenshot i have provided i want the scrollbar to be always updated to stay at the bottom when a new message comes through/ page loaded.

```
<div class='media'>
      <a class='pull-left' href='#'>
          <img class='media-object img-circle' src='img/avatar' alt='Avatar'>
      </a>

      <div class='media-body'>
            <h5 class='media-heading'>/username/</h5>
            <h5>/message/</h5>
      </div>
</div><hr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this function

```
var makescrollbottom = function(){
    $("div.media").scrollTop($("div.media").prop("scrollHeight"));
}
makescrollbottom();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/d2tyyo9q/1/) another [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/d2tyyo9q/3/)

for more explain with append see this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/d2tyyo9q/5/)

Comment: Is there anywhere else you could show the demo? jsfiddle doesnt seem to be responding for me at the moment, and it doesn't seem to be working for me so i wanted to check a demo

Comment: Thankyou! Helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**For pure JavaScript**, you only need to update the value of **scrollTop** to **scrollHeigh** value.

The picture below illustrates **scrollHeight** and **scrollTop** for a vertically scrollable box.

[image]

For example:

```
var myChatBox = ocument.getElementById("myChatBox");
myChatBox.scrollTop = myChatBox.scrollHeight;
```

Link to jsFiddle demo --> [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/FacuCode/s79qr06L/)

For further information about JavaScript metrics click [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/metrics)